# MSBuild wildcard matching of files for deployment

Tags: msbuild

I am hoping to be able to use MSBuild to capture a subtree of files produced during the build of a project using Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web and include them in deployment. So far, I have found that if I simply create the files inside the project folder before deployment, then it works but only for certain filetypes. DLLs, for instance, are excluded, presumably assumed to be non-content items. I have been poking around how the deployment stuff works, and have found the `<ResolvedFileToPublish>` element that I can put into `<ItemGroup>`, but I haven't figured out how it might be possible to employ this with wildcards. Specifically, I have a post-build step that places files into a folder `deployment` within the project, and I want *all* files in that subtree to be included in the package that is produced by `/p:DeployOnBuild=true`. How can I tack my files onto the deployment stage so that they're included in the ZIP even if they don't look like content items?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, in the form of adding a new `<Task>` set to run immediately after the internal tasks which collect files for publishing. This is not suitable for a long-term solution, since it ties to internal state, but this is a temporary fix and as such I think it's alright.

By adding this to the .csproj:

```
  <Target Name="__CopyDeploymentToPublish" AfterTargets="_CopyResolvedFilesToPublishAlways">
    <Exec Command="PowerShell.exe -Version 3.0 -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted $(SolutionDir)deploy_webapp.ps1 -Source $(SolutionDir)src\IQ.Auth.OAuth2.Web -Target $(PublishDir)" />
  </Target>
```

...my PowerShell script runs right after the standard deployment logic aggregates the files it intends to package up. I can at that point do whatever I want to the files and the way they're left is what'll end up in the ZIP file.